# How to avoid duplication in Model Manager by using ValueError in model method

Tags: python, django, django-models, exception

I worked through documentation / examples to get to the code below. It works, but I'd like to receive some help from an experienced developer as this is not the most efficient code:

- Checking_account.objects.get(user=request.user) is used 2 times (in the model manager and the view)
- ‘Not enough cash’ check is performed 2 times (in the model manager and the view)

Question: is it possible to use the “ValueError” raised in the model method as trigger to display a message in the template + the link towards the "deposit_checkin_account_page" (and in this way avoid duplication in the Model Manager & view) or should this be solved in a complete different way?

All suggestions are welcome! Thanks!

Models.py:

```
class Checking_accountManager(models.Manager):
    def check_balance(self, user, value):
        if Checking_account.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
            checking_account = Checking_account.objects.get(user=user)
            if value <= checking_account.current_balance:
                return True
        else:
            return False


class Checking_account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_balance = models.DecimalField(_('Balans'), max_digits=18, decimal_places=8, default=0)

    objects = Checking_accountManager()

    def deposit(self, value):
        self.current_balance += value
        self.save()

    def withdraw(self, value):
        if value > self.current_balance:
            raise ValueError('not enough cash')
        self.current_balance -= value
        self.save()
```

Views.py:

```
view buy (request, item):
    item = item.objects.get(item=item)
    cost = item.cost

    if Checking_account.objects.check_balance(user=request.user, value=quote_cost):
        checking_account = Checking_account.objects.get(user=request.user)
        checking_account.withdraw(cost)
        messages.success(request, _('Succes.'))
    else:
        messages.error(request, _('no checking account yet or not enough cash.'))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(‘<deposit_checkin_account_page>’)
    return render(request, ‘buy.html')
```

EDIT - 19/03/2017

Based on answer Daniel Roseman I've changed code to the following:

models.py
remove the model manager

views.py

```
try:
    request.user.checking_account.withdraw(quote_cost)
    messages.success(request, _('Succes.'))
except (ObjectDoesNotExist, ValueError):
    messages.error(request, _('no checking account yet or not enough cash.'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('deposit_checking_account'))
return render(request, ‘buy.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's even worse than that, because you also unnecessarily hit the database for the `exists()` call. Don't do any of that; instead, just follow the one-to-one relation from user:

```
checking_account = user.checking_account
```